# Explicit and Recursive Exponential Growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

The population of a certain organism triples every hour. Write a function that models this growth. By what factor does the population grow in one-half hour?

I'm unsure of how I should approach the problem. Since I do not know f(0), I'd just assume that: f(x) = x^3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^3$ is polynomial growth, what you want is exponential growth. Try $f(x)=P_03^x$ instead for the first part of the question. $P_0$ represents the initial population.

Comment: Thanks, I'm forgetting that, but I'm also confused on how to answer the question? Is it just the formula with 0.5 for x?

Comment: Yes, $x=.5$ will give you the factor.